# Try to get only one array

Tags: javascript

I try to get only one array with different element but for the moment I have different array ...

```
// ********* SOME CODE *********

var color = [];
var risk = []; 
var all_operational = [];

if(Operational.length == group.name.length){
    color = "green";
    risk = "Operational";
    all_operational.push(group.name);
    console.log(all_operational);
}

/* console.log(group.name) 
   OUTPUT: toto
           tata
           titi
           trtr
```

Actual result (console.log(all_operational):

- ['toto'] ['tata'] ['titi'] ['trtr']

Expexted result :

- ['toto','tata','titi','trtr']

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate

Comment: Provide 'Operational', 'group', string is not usefull also, why are you assigning strings to arrays (color and risk) ? If your output is an array of array, this is because group.name is itself an array, use shift() to get the element out

Comment: Is that code actually in a loop? You're likely overwriting the `all_operational` array in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `group.name` is an array. If it's supposed to be like this you can flatten the all_operational with `.flat()` method. Try `console.log(all_operational.flat())`.